# Complex inheritance scenario

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Let's say you need to build an application that manages cheques. Each cheque contains data about the amount of money, the date, the payee and an additional payment date which may or may not be present. Additionally, each cheque must be related to a current account which belongs to a certain bank.
Now, our application should allow cheques printing under these conditions:

- Each bank managed by the app has a different cheque layout (i.e. each field has a different x,y position).
- The cheque layout changes slightly if the payment date is present, even with the same related bank object. But, from bank to bank these changes may not be the same (e.g. bank A may vary position for the date field, while bank B changes position for the payee field)

With these restrictions in place, it's difficult to come up with a simple inheritance schema as there is no consistent behavior to factor out accross the different types of cheques there are. One possible solution would be to avoid inheritance and create a class for every cheque - bank combination:

- class ChequeNoPaymentDateForBankA
- class ChequeWithPaymentDateForBankA
- class ChequeNoPaymentDateForBankB
- class ChequeWithPaymentDateForBankB, etc.

Each of these classes implement the print() method which takes the fields positions from a Bank object and builds up the cheque layout. So far so good, but this approach leaves me with a strange feeling as there is no room for code reuse. I wonder if I'm misinterpreting the problem and perhaps there is a better way. As this is not a new problem domain at all, I'm sure this is a reinvent-the-wheel effort. Any insights will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: If they all have the same components with different coordinates, you could consider just having different constructors in the same object.

Comment: maybe a partial use of the  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern that does the printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by separating the domain model (cheques, banks, etc) from the view (the way the cheques are printed). This is the basic idea behind the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern and one of its aims is to allow the same domain model to be displayed in different ways (which seems to be your case). So, I would first create the domain classes, something like:

```
class Cheque 
{
protected $bank;
protected $money;
...
}

class Bank {...}
```

Note that these classes are the "M" of the MVC triad and implement the logic of your domain model, not the behavior related to the rendering process. The next step would be to implement the View classes used to render a cheque. Which approach to take heavily depends on how complex your rendering is, but I would start by having a `ChequeView` class that renders the common parts and that delegates to other sub-view the specific parts that can change (in this case the date):

```
abstract class ChequeView
{
protected $cheque;
protected $dateView;

public function __construct($cheque)
{
  $this->cheque = $cheque;
  $this->dateView = //Whatever process you use to decide if the payment date is shown or not
}

public function render()
{
  $this->coreRender();
  $this->dateView->render();
}

abstract protected function coreRender();
}

class BankACheckView extends ChequeView
{
protected function coreRender() {...}
}

class BankBCheckView extends ChequeView
{
protected function coreRender() {...}
}

abstract class DateView
{
abstract function render()
}

class ShowDateView extends DateView
{
function render() {...}
}

class NullDateView extends DateView
{
function render() {...}
}
```

And, if there is code to reuse across subclasses, you can of course factor them in `ChequeView` and make `coreRender()` call them.

In case your rendering turns to be too complex, this design may not scale. In that case I would go for splitting your view in meaningful subparts (e.g. `HeaderView`, `AmountView`, etc) so that rendering a cheque becomes basically rendering its different sub-parts. In this case the `ChequeView` may end basically working as a [Composite](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html). Finally, if you reach this case and setting up the `ChequeView` turns out to be a complex task you may want to use a [Builder](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html).

**Edit based on the OP comments**

The Builder is mostly used when the instantiation of the final object is a complex process (e.g. there are many things to sync between the sub-parts in order to get a consistent whole). There is generally one builder class and different clients, that send messages (potentially in different orders and with different arguments) to create a variety of final objects. So, while not prohibited, it is not usual to have one builder per type of object that you want to build.

If you are looking for a class that represents the creation of a particular instance you may want to check the [Factory](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) family of patterns (maybe the [Abstract Factory](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html) resembles closely to what you had in mind).

HTH

Comment: I think you got the point, and splitting the cheque fields into separated rendering components was one of my options except that i never thought about the Builder pattern. As you say, scaling is critical in this case, so I'm taking Builder as the way to go.

Comment: I guess that to apply the Builder pattern I'd have to create a builder class for every cheque - bank combination, similar to my original suggestion. In this case, `ChequeWithPaymentDateForBankA` would become `ChequeWithPaymentDateForBankABuilder` to create a rendering object. Additionaly, I'd need a collection of `PrintingItem` instances which would carry the x,y positions and a text field. Finally, the rendering object would have a `print()` method which simply walks through each `PrintingItem` and prints them.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Where it says **builder** in my comment should be **concrete builder**. There is only one builder class that defines the `print()` abstract method (maybe an interface would be enough here) and several concrete builders, one for every cheque - bank combination. The director class would be responsible for selecting the right concrete buider for the job based upon some information coming from the cheque model object.

Comment: Is it "legal" to have one concrete builder extend another concrete builder instead of inheriting the abstract builder class directly? That way, I could reuse even more code by including only the fields that need to be changed from one concrete builder to another.

Comment: Patterns are design guidelines that capture solutions to common problems and you can adapt them to suit your needs. So, in principle, it seems ok. I would however try a different (and IMHO more elegant) approach: have the builder be a single class that takes care of putting the pieces together and have a separate factory hierarchy hold the details of each `Cheque` graphic layout. In that way you have a clear separation of responsibilities (building process vs. instance configuration). HTH

Answer (score 1):

Usually in these situations I move from inheritance to delegation. That is, instead of putting the common code in a superclass (which, as you say, is problematic becuase there are two dimensions), I put the common in a field (one field per dimension) and delegate to that field.

Assuming you're speaking about Java:

```
public interface Bank {
   public void print();
}

public class BankA implements Bank {
   public void print() { ... }
}

public class BankB implements Bank {
   public void print() { ... }
}


public interface PaymentSchedule {
   public void print();
}

public class WithPaymentDate implements PaymentSchedule {
   public void print() { ... }    
}

public class NoPaymentDate implements PaymentSchedule {
   public void print() { ... }    
}

public class Cheque {
  private final Bank bank;
  private final PaymentSchedule schedule;


  public Cheque(Bank b, PaymentSchedule s) {
     bank = b;
     schedule = s;
  }


  public void print() {
     bank.print();
     schedule.print();
  }
}
```

That's the general structure of the solution.

Depending on the exact details of your print() algorithm you may need to pass some more data into the print methods and/or to pass this data into the constructors of the classes (of the Bank or PaymentSchedule subclasses) and store it in fields.

Comment: This is a very good start point, but the problem is that it's hard to factor out common code and putting it into a Bank class because what a bank prints (I mean the positions and the fields themselves) changes dependending on the presence of the payment date.